# error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Subchild> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

Hi I have one xml file successfully parsed my before. now i am change simple modification in my xml file after i am getting lot of error. how to solve this error i don't know i post my my xml file 1st and am using sax parser.

i have two spinner if i click 1st spinner its shows test1, test2, test3 then i select test1 its shows test1 sub tag name stest1 to stest5. if select test2 my 2nd spinner show stest6 to stest10 this is my working xml file output now i am trying to add one tag in sltag from my xml file already my sltag display name tag now i am add  here my problem is started. my problem is how to get both values into my sltag i need separate string value so i passed class in my sltag array list and create class also after declare name and path into array list then how to get both string value My purpose is when i select 2nd spinner value that i want to show some images in same screen bottom i trying to get path string value.

This is my error:
1. error line: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to ArrayList

line

source link: http://paste.org/42566

other java files link here:

http://paste.org/42567

http://paste.org/42568

http://paste.org/42569

Comment: i wish to get path string value from sltag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getSLTag` is declared to return an `ArrayList<String>` but the variable `sltag` in the `xmlTag` class is actually an `ArrayList<SubChild>` hence the type mismatch.

So to answer your additional comment about wanting to get path string from sltag, you will need to iterate over the collection of `SubChild`s and add each path to a new List of Strings, e.g.

```
public ArrayList<String> getSLTag(String hltag) {
    List<String> slTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < xmlTagInfo.size(); i++) {
        if( xmlTagInfo.get(i).hltag == hltag ) {
            for (SubChild child : xmlTagInfo.get(i).sltag) {
                // Your SubChild class actually declares path and name to be an ArrayList of Strings, but surely they should just be Strings?
                slTags.add(child.getPath());
            }
        }
    }
    return slTags;
}
```

Comment: i am not familiar in java pls help correct my source code pls