# Error : String cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I am trying to get my `sltag` value but I got some errors in my code. Please help me solve this error.

I have one XML file. I want to display that XML file node value one spinner and child node value value one tab etc... so I am using a SAX parser.

error lines

```
public ArrayList<Subchild> getSLTag() {
    ArrayList<String> SLTag = new ArrayList <Sting>();
    for(int i = 0; i<xmlTagInfo.size(); i++);
    SLTag.add(xmlTagInfo.get(i).sltag);
}
```

2nd and 4th line error error is

1. Multiple markers at this line

   - Sting cannot be resolved to a type
   - ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
2. i cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you improve your question by correcting obvious mistakes? I can only speak for myself, but I don't like to read questions that are hard to read/understand because of poor language.

Comment: For our sake and yours, please use an IDE.

Comment: @migu Couldn't agree more. I just move to another question now.

Comment: And this question is ***very*** similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574402/error-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-arraylistsubchild-to-arrayliststrin. It even shows up in the right hand side related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already gave some solutions. What's more:

```
for(int i = 0; i<xmlTagInfo.size(); i++);
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<xmlTagInfo.size(); i++)
```

Comment: error : The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (ArrayList<Subchild>)

Comment: That error appears about right doesn't it? You're adding objects to `SLTag` (bad name) which are of the wrong type. So, you either change `SLTag` or make sure what you add are `String`s.

Comment: My guess: `SLTag` should be of type `ArrayList<Subchild>` and you should use `addAll` instead of `add`.

Comment: Did you also change `SLTag`? Like so: `ArrayList<Subchild> SLTag = new ArrayList<Subchild>();`

Comment: Then you cannot get the same error. I need to see the code you have now plus error messages to be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have misspelled `String` in your code. You have placed `Sting`. (cool guy by the way, love the song "Fields of gold")
2. To use ArrayList you need to include `import java.util.ArrayList` at the top of your sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

it's spell mistake in this statement

```
ArrayList<String> SLTag = new ArrayList <Sting>(); // check the spell
```

it's String not Sting

```
ArrayList<String> SLTag = new ArrayList <String>();
```